# State with Local storage doesn't work on saving theme

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add theme switcher for dark/light mode on my website using localStorage, state and effect from React. And it just doesn't work, I can't find wrong logic (from my view) and I don't know what to do, here is the senario:

Here is my logic:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === null) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'lightmode');
      setTheme('lightmode');
    }
    else if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'lightmode') {
      setTheme('lightmode')
    }
    else if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'darkmode') {
      setTheme('darkmode')
    }
  }, [])

  function change_theme() {
    if (theme === 'lightmode') {
      setTheme('lightmode')
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'lightmode');
      document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");
      document.body.classList.add("lightmode");
    } else {
      setTheme('darkmode')
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'darkmode');
      document.body.classList.remove("lightmode");
      document.body.classList.add("darkmode");
    };
  }
```

And here is my JSX:

```
{
 theme === 'lightmode' ?
   <button onClick={() => change_theme()}>Change Mode</button>
    :
   <button onClick={() => change_theme()}>Change Mode</button>
}
```

Comment: What does `setTheme` do?

Comment: @abdusco all what you see in this code, nothing else is outside

Comment: In which scope is the `theme` from `change_theme` declared and changed? There seems to be some code missing here. If theme is a regular variable, you should treat it as state if you want something to change. Additionally I advise creating `change_theme` via a `useCallback` that's dependant on the `theme` state

Answer (score 0):

in the change_theme() function you are setting the theme the same it already is.

Solution:

```
  function change_theme() {
    if (theme === 'darkmode') { // <--- this was the mistake
      setTheme('lightmode')
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'lightmode');
      document.body.classList.remove("darkmode");
      document.body.classList.add("lightmode");
    } else {
      setTheme('darkmode')
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'darkmode');
      document.body.classList.remove("lightmode");
      document.body.classList.add("darkmode");
    };
  }
```

You only need one button. the terniery statement is not needed, since the change_theme() function already checks the theme.

```
<button onClick={change_theme}>Change Mode</button>
```

Comment: I'm using images for button, but didn't included here for simplicity this is why i used two same buttons in {}

Comment: Did the other part of my solution fix the problem ? @neyeror358

Comment: becuase i posted it earlier and i was able to fix it somehow, If i don't forget i will upload my solution